# Google map V2 is no brightness and not clear

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have used mapfragment to display google map v2. It is visible but mapV2 is not clear, 
that means brightness is low even when my phone brightness is 100%.

I used the code below to display the map,

```
googleMap = fragment.getMap();
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Can you post the screenshot ?

Comment: i dont have reputation to post screen shot

Comment: you can use an image upload site...

Comment: ... or even better: earn the reputation and put an image here.

Comment: ya k i can do like that